# Как правильно описать схему, когда одна сущность с уникальным идентификатором может ссылаться на сущности разных категорий?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Ситуация: есть веб-приложение, интегрируемой с телефонией. В приложении используется много сущностей (сотрудник, объект, обслуживающая организация и т.д.), которые могут иметь по несколько телефонов. При этом все телефоны в пределах базы должны быть уникальными, т.е. не может быть одинакового телефона у сотрудника и у обслуживающей организации. Делается это для того, чтобы однозначно идентифицировать звонящего при входящем звонке.
Вопрос: как правильно описать такую схему? Сейчас я описываю сущность телефона так:

```
class Phone(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'phones'

phone = db.Column(db.String(13), primary_key=True)
note = db.Column(db.String(30))
employee_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('employees.id'))
object_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('objects.id'))
special_force_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('special_forces.id'))

employee = db.relationship('Employee', backref='phones')
object = db.relationship('Object', backref='control_phones')
special_force = db.relationship('SpecialForce', backref='phones')
```

Но может есть более правильный способ? И как можно сделать ограничение, чтобы телефон, связанный с организацией нельзя было одновременно связать с сотрудником?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте полиморфные отношения. Как раз ваш пример в документации http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/inheritance.html

```python
class ModelWithPhone(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'phones'
    phone = Column(String(13), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'phone',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }



class Employee(ModelWithPhone):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('phones.phone'), primary_key=True)
    employee_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'employee',
    }

class Object(ModelWithPhone):
    __tablename__ = 'object'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('phones.phone'), primary_key=True)
    object_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'object',
    }

class SpecialForce(ModelWithPhone):
    __tablename__ = 'special_force'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('phones.phone'), primary_key=True)
    special_force_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'special_force',
    }
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).